# Can I prevent IMAP from grabbing files over X mb using PHP?

Tags: php, imap

I'm building a little script that will connect to an IMAP account and grab the content of the email and also the attachments.  It works well for the most part, but when a really large file comes in, it causes the script to time out.  Is there any way that I can check the file size before trying to grab it?  I think that would be the simplest solution.  Otherwise, I may have  to upgrade to a server that has more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [imap-fetch-overview()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php) and [imap-fetchstructure()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php)

They look like they'll give you the size in bytes (depending on the server).

Comment: I'm currently using imap_fetchstructure() and I just noticed it passes back bytes.  How exactly does imap_fetchstructure() work? Does it actually grab the attachments right when you call it?

Comment: `imap_fetchstructure()` will not fetch the attachments; it asks the IMAP server to return the structure to you (yes, there is an IMAP command to do that). Then you use `imap_fetchbody()` to get the bit you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [imap_fetch_overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php) to retrieve information for one or more headers, including the size.